# Virus Effected to my pendrive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus

I am using scandisk 8 GB pendrive. I am a programmer so I put my project details and my projects in that pendrive, by using folders. Now the problem is that my folders are becomig hidden, when I am using the unhide option in the page options. It may again become hidden with in fraction of seconds; the hidden option in the properties are hidden, then what is the solution?

Comment: I don't understand... so basically your folders are staying permanently hidden?

Comment: yes and i want to retrieve the files to visible mode

Answer (score 7):

Try using the pendrive on a Linux computer.  Not only will Linux ignore most viruses that are on the drive, but also see all files regardless if they are hidden.

It actually sounds like your computer has a virus, not just the thumb drive.  You should see the question: [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score -1):

1. Vaccinate your pendrives (there is a method to make pendrives safe, but if I publish it here, virus authors will catch up. so spend 10 minutes thinking how to do that and go on.)
2. Install an anti-vir that blocks viruses run by autorun.inf AND google for usb firewall app.

To fix current situation:

- Download and burn an Ubuntu desktop `.iso`.
- Put in CD drive and run Live
- Plug your pendrive and copy data or fix stuff.
  Destroy `autorun.inf` and all Recycle-alike folders and weird named `.exe` files

In Windows:

- Install a firewall and anti virus software.
- After finding out the name of the worm, Google for more help.
- Get a `.reg` file that fixes access to hidden files.

Comment: Hey, why that response was -2? It is also ok!

Comment: I wrote "sh.t" instead of viruses once and that ruined the whole answer for some people...

Comment: It's probably because you assumed that the OP is able to switch his OS. This is not really possible in a work environment, given that he is working in projects this is most likely the case...

Comment: Yeah, the answer that is +7 just says use linux always, while I suggested running a liveCD once